# Список словарей?

Tags: python, api

Есть необходимость отправлять смс на номера потребителей услуг. По одной смс отправлять получается, но не могу понять как создать список словарей, возможно не правильно взял направление и нужен не список словарей, а что-то другое.

ключи одинаковые для всех номеров телефонов, значение не меняется только у shortcode (подпись смс с названием организации).

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

req = requests.post(
    'https://target.tele2.ru/api/v2/send_message', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('123456789', '123456789'),
    data=dict(msisdn="79*********", shortcode="text", text='test2'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создать список с данными, которые включают номера телефонов и `text` сущность, например такой

```py
to_send = [{"tel":"79********1", "text":"test1"},
           {"tel":"79********2", "text":"test2"},
           {"tel":"79********3", "text":"test3"}]
```

А далее отправлять запросы через цикл, для каждой сущности в переменной `to_send`

```py
responses = {}
for item in to_send:
    req = requests.post(
         'https://target.tele2.ru/api/v2/send_message', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('123456789', '123456789'),
          data=dict(msisdn=item["tel"], shortcode="text", text=item["text"]))
    responses[item["tel"]] = req.status_code
```

Так же добавил словарь, в который будут копиться статусы ответов от каждого запроса.
То есть на выходе можно проверить данный словарь и он будет содержать примерно следующее:

```py
{
    "79********1":200,
    "79********2":200,
    "79********3":200
}
```

Comment: Большое спсибо!

Comment: На здоровье. Обратите внимание на [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: А можно еще вопрос? Для to_send как взять данные из csv?

Comment: @humanian да, конечно можно. Есть несколько способов в зависимости от того какие входные данные у вас в csv. Лушее решение это обратиться к поиску на SO или создать новый вопрос, указав формат входящих данных и что хотите иметь на выходе.